# DataTable does not re-draw after updating rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the [DataTables](https://datatables.net) library to create a table with extra functionality. What I'd like to achieve, is that the user can select rows and then press a button. This will call the server, do some stuff and the rows should be updated accordingly.

However, after I'm done iterating over the rows to be changed and setting its values, re-drawing the table does not actually update its values. I update the data object, invalidate the cache and call `table.draw()`. It's very similar to the last example on [this page](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()).

I have created a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sopascnq/)** of this issue. The button updates the date objects of the selected rows and the table is re-drawn, but the data inside the table is not updated. The core JS code:

```
$('#updateRow').click(function() {
    //Get the table
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    //Iterate over selected rows
    var rowData = table.rows({
        selected: true
    }).every(function() {
        //For every selected row, update startDate
        var d = this.data();
        d.startDate = "01/01/2017";
        console.log('Set startDate of ' + d.name + ' to ' + d.startDate);
        //Invalidate the cache
        this.invalidate();
    });
    //Re-draw the table
    table.draw();
});
```

Comment: try with "Destroy":true

Comment: @IvanBarayev Doesn't seem to make any difference sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked and did the solution from your JsFiddle. Here's the relevant snippet from fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k38r9be5/1/

```
var rowData = table.rows({
    selected: true
}).every(function(rowIdx) {
    var colIdx = 4; // startDate is the fifth column, or "4" from 0-base  (0,1,2,3,4...)
    table.cell( rowIdx, colIdx).data('01/01/2017').draw();
});
```

Basically, via the API you can get the cell object itself, and modify the contents with .data(). In your version you weren't actually getting a particular cell object and instead just copied the data contents of the row to a variable, and modified that.

Comment: I found it a bit odd to update the cell itself if the DataTable is backed by said data. Especially since the example in their documentation also edits data and re-draws. But it solves the issue! Thank you